# Jmeter breaks the "authenticity_token" value in two keys due to ampersand present in it

Tags: http-post, jmeter, ampersand, authenticity-token

Following value of authenticity_token getting truncated due to ampersand(&) in value.

```
authenticity_token=CUYGx8Wsvc4wVrqdqBSB0ePSvIZnRfh1Qf&#47;XOWnekQc=
```

Due to this POST request is getting failed in Jmeter

HTTP format of POST request which got truncated :

[image]

Raw Format of same POST request :

```
POST http://abcdomain.com/punter/punteradmin/languages

POST data:
utf8=✓&authenticity_token=A7Fkebd2rYIyHF%26%2347%3Bn1Mm44p0iiRh%2BCRX4cTtVlrksHUU%3D&language[name]=Test Lang B&language[code]=ab-BB&commit=Add Language

Cookie Data:
$Version=0; _session_id=22795fce48a3f49d99b9d09a7a6aae07; $Path=/

Request Headers:
Content-Length: 154
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 0):

In your POST request ensure you check in parameters table the Encode column for the token parameter.

[image]